# Find the closest distance between every galaxy in the data and create pairs based on closest distance between them

Tags: python-3.x, loops, python-itertools, astropy, fits

My task is to pair up galaxies that are closest together from a large list of galaxies. I have the RA, DEC and Z of each, and a formula to work out the distance between each one from the data given. However, I can't work out an efficient method of iterating over the whole list to find the distance between EACH galaxy and EVERY other galaxy in the list, with the intention of then matching each galaxy with its nearest neighbour.

The data has been imported in the following way:

```
    hdulist = fits.open("documents/RADECMASSmatch.fits")
    CATAID = data['CATAID_1']
    Xpos_DEIMOS_1 = data['Xpos_DEIMOS_1']
    z = data['Z_1']
    RA = data['RA']
    DEC = data['DEC']
```

I have tried something like:

```
    radiff = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            radiff.append(abs(RA[i]-RA[j]))
```

to initially work out difference in RA and DEC between every galaxy, which does actually work but I feel like there must be a better way.

A friend suggested something along the lines of:

```
    galaxy_coords = (data['RA'],data['DEC'],data['Z])
    separation_matrix = np.zeros((len(galaxy_coords),len(galaxy_coords))

    done = []
    for i, coords1 in enumerate(galaxy_coords):
          for j, coords2 in enumerate(galaxy_coords):
                if (j,i) in done:
                    separation_matrix[i,j] += separation matrix[j,i]
                    continue
                    separation = your_formula(coords1, coords2)
                    separation_matrix[i,j] += separation
                    done.append((i,j))
```

But I don't really understand this so can't readily apply it. I've tried but it yields nothing useful.

Any help with this would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Have you looked whether [`astropy.coordinates`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/matchsep.html#astropy-coordinates-matching) is any use for you. It can match catalogs (though it will not automatically create pairs for you). It uses scipy's kd-tree under the hood.

Comment: Not sure it helps me for this first phase, but looks like it will be very helpful for the next where I need to change to a new coordinate system based on the line of separation of each galaxy pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend's code seems to be generating a 2D array of the distances between each pair, and taking advantage of the symmetry (distance(x,y) = distance(y,x)). It would be slightly better if it used itertools to generate combinations, and assigned `your_formula(coords1, coords2)` to  `separation_matrix[i,j]` and `separation_matrix[j,i]` within the same iteration, rather than having separate iterations for both i,j and j,i.

Even better would probably be this package that uses a tree-based algorithm: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html . It seems to be focused on rectilinear coordinates, but that should be addressable in linear time.

Comment: Would you be able to show me what you mean? I'm not overly familiar with itertools and iterative coding generally. Thanks

Comment: If you do `itertools.combinations(len(galaxy_coords),2)`, it will give you every pair of distinct indices from 0 to len(galaxy_coords)-1. It won't give you pairs of the form (i,i), and if it gives you (i,j), it won't give you (j,i). Since you know the distance from anything to itself is zero, and the distance from galaxy[i] to galaxy[j] is the same as the distance from galaxy[j] to galaxy[i], this gives you all the pairs you need.